# Can GNU/Linux software run on GNU/Hurd?

Tags: linux, gnu, hurd

I am only familiar with the GNU/Linux system and I recently discovered the Hurd kernel, so the first question that came up in my mind was: is the software that I can find on a GNU/Linux system able to run on a GNU/Hurd system? Does the compatibility come from the kernel or the GNU operating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to binaries, no, you can't run GNU/Linux binaries on a GNU/Hurd system. Compatibility involves a number of factors, including the kernel; any binary which accesses resources managed by the kernel (including, notably, file access) will end up including kernel-specific information, such as how to invoke the kernel (syscalls etc.).

Calling a distribution “GNU/Linux” isn't a claim that it's compatible with the [GNU operating system](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/about-gnu.html), in particular it's not a claim that it's compatible with a putative GNU operative system using the [Hurd](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/). It's simply a name which is meant to recognise [the contributions of the GNU project](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/why-gnu-linux.html). See [Is it possible to run pure GNU?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90883/is-it-possible-to-run-pure-gnu) for more info on the GNU operating system, although these days the GNU project itself refers to Linux-based distributions as the GNU operating system (as long as they meet the Free Software Foundation's requirements).

You can build GNU/Hurd-based systems very similar to GNU/Linux-based systems; [Debian GNU/Hurd](https://www.debian.org/ports/hurd/) is one example. You could also (theoretically) develop an emulation layer for Linux binaries on Hurd (similar to the [iBCS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Binary_Compatibility_Standard) compatibility layer for Linux in the past).